# Firebase Admin FCM Send Messages doesnt work

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I did exactly like it is described
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages

my code:

```
Message message = Message.builder()
    .putData("title", "850")
    .putData("body", "2:45")
    .setTopic("topic")
    .build();

String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```

result:

> Successfully sent message:
>   projects/gcm-1234/messages/5525078879722149927

but when I go:
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/gcm-1234/notification

I dont see any new message, also I do not get message on phone, but When I send meassage from firebase console it works also on phone.

Where I can find this message? Why It doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Where I can find this message?
```

Even the message was sent correctly. It will not appear in Firebase Console. This is how it was designed.

> Why It doesnt work?

To send a notification, the payload must use the notification key:

```
.setNotification(new Notification("test","test"))};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me, when using the **[Node.js SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin)**, was not setting the `webpush` attribute.

```
import * as firebaseMessaging from 'firebase-admin/messaging'

firebaseMessaging.getMessaging().send(
  {
    token: '<fcmToken>',
    webpush: {
      notification: {
        title: 'title',
        body: 'body',
      },
    },
  },
  false
)
```

When I was only using the `notification` attribute instead of the `webpush` attribute, I would get a valid message id but not receive anything in the app.